# "en la tarde" vs "de la tarde" vs "por la tarde"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

I am trying to tell the difference between these three phrases in Spanish.
When would you use each, or do they all mean the same thing?

What would be the following translations?

> Bob is going to the beach this afternoon.
>
> I went to the beach yesterday night.
>
> This morning I will eat breakfast.